# How to delete rows with a condition in a database?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have my dataset which involves userID and gamecodes. There are 23 users and various game codes, I used:

`df.groupby('Game Code')['User ID'].nunique().sort_values(ascending=False).head(60)`

OUTPUT:

![Output][1]

There were 59 repeats. Now I want to remove those rows that give a value of less than 2 for this condition

An example to work with:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"UserId": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], "GameCode": ["a", "a", "c", "b", "d", "a", "b", "e"]})
df.groupby('GameCode')['UserId'].nunique().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
GameCode
a    3
b    2
e    1
d    1
c    1
Name: UserId, dtype: int64
```

I would like to drop rows that have an output of 2 or more.

So get this back:

```
 UserId GameCode
0   1   a
1   1   a
2   2   c
3   2   b
4   3   d
5   4   e
Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgRuk.png
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your question suffers a lack of clarity. It is not evident what you're trying to do. Please explain!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a groupby, similar to what you did, to isolate the values with 2 or more occurrences. Then you can filter the dataframe to exclude those values:

g = df.groupby("GameCode").size()

df = df[~df["GameCode"].isin(g[g>=2].index)]